# Coding to Interface not to Implementation

Tags: java, list, design-patterns

According to the Designing principle,**"Coding to interface not to implementation".**

I come up with a doubt by designing simple program.As a beginner i have this question which is given below,

```
 import java.util.*;

    public class HelloWorld{

         public static void main(String []args){
            Map<Integer,String> test = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
            test.put(1,"Sridhar");
            test.put(2,"Lord Balaji");
            test.put(3,"Ragavendra");
            test.put(4,"Jai Krishna");
            Set testObject = test.keySet();
            LinkedList<Integer> normal = new LinkedList<Integer>();
         //   List<Integer> interfaceImpl = new LinkedList<Integer>();
         //   interfaceImpl.addAll(testObject);
         //   System.out.println(interfaceImpl);
         //   System.out.println("The keys are:"+interfaceImpl.getFirst());
            normal.addAll(testObject);
            System.out.println(normal);
            System.out.println("The keys are:"+normal.getFirst());
         }
    }
```

**Uncomment the lines** on the above code ,which is the coding to interface **List** design.

But designing as per the design pattern,i got the compile error.

whether this error is violating the designing principle in java or I have misunderstood the concept.so Just give me good explanation to recover from this.

Thank You

Comment: compilation error is because you have Maptest without spaces. Modify to Map test. Also List does not have getFirst() method, which will also throw compilation error.

Comment: List does not have a getFirst method, this is a method of the implementation not the interface...

Comment: I know that getFirst() is not in the interface,then why designing principles states like that ?

Comment: @JAVABeginner you're using the wrong interface ;) Look at the JavaDoc for `LinkedList`; it implements several, one of which specifies `getFirst()`

Comment: yeah @ brian I got cleared :) Java always rocks :) its simply the Deque interface from where the LinkedList is implementing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface deque which is suppose to perform front and back insertion deletion etc. This interface have been implemented by LinkedList.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Map<Integer,String>test = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        test.put(1,"Sridhar");
        test.put(2,"Lord Balaji");
        test.put(3,"Ragavendra");
        test.put(4,"Jai Krishna");
        Set testObject = test.keySet();
        LinkedList<Integer> normal = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Deque<Integer> interfaceImpl = new LinkedList<Integer>(); //Here Design principle works
        interfaceImpl.addAll(testObject);
        System.out.println(interfaceImpl);
        System.out.println("The keys are:"+interfaceImpl.getFirst());
        normal.addAll(testObject);
        System.out.println(normal);
        System.out.println("The keys are:"+normal.getFirst());
     }
}
```

Now It is cleared :) thanks for all your comments

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your generic types, and check your **variable names** -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<Integer, String> test = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
  test.put(1, "Sridhar");
  test.put(2, "Lord Balaji");
  test.put(3, "Ragavendra");
  test.put(4, "Jai Krishna");
  Set<Integer> testObject = test.keySet();
  LinkedList<Integer> normal = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  List<Integer> interfaceImpl = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // <-- Note this works too!
  interfaceImpl.addAll(testObject);
  System.out.println(interfaceImpl);
  // A list, not necessarily a LinkedList...
  System.out.println("The keys are:"
      + interfaceImpl.iterator().next());
  normal.addAll(testObject);
  System.out.println(normal);
  System.out.println("The keys are:"
      + normal.getFirst());
}
```

Which outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
The keys are:1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
The keys are:1
```

Comment: LinkedList<Integer> normal = new LinkedList<Integer>(); this line only i have error cos i was typed to interface...now i come to know that list interface doesnt have that getFirst() method.Design principle is fails in this case ?

Comment: No. You didn't code to the interface. getting the `iterator()` and then calling `next()` will work for all List(s) (including `LinkedList`). Your method demonstrates the issue addressed by the pattern because it only works with `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not run your code and I cannot tell you the exact mistake. When you execute something against an interface, it means that you can execute **the methods defined in the interface**. So, I suppose that you call some method defined the class **implementing the interface** which causes the error.

The `getFirst` method is defined in the `LinkedList` and not in the `List` interface. When you use it in the rest of your code, you depend your code in the `LinkedList` class which is not as generic as the `List` interface.

This "code against interface" principle helps you to have the rest of your code independent of (not depending on) a specific interface implementation (like `LinkedList`). Therefore, you should find another way of finding the first element in your list, using the methods of the `List` interface. You could also check [this post which explains the whole idea](http://www.fatagnus.com/program-to-an-interface-not-an-implementation/).

Hope I helped!